# Neo4j - How to display a graph of Nodes connected to properties of related nodes

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-browser

I have Nodes Customer and Product - with a directed relationship TRANSACTION from Customer to Product.
Product has the property `category`.

Is it possible to display all the Customers connected to all the categories which they have bought? As though the categories were a node rather than a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [APOC Virtual Nodes and Relationships](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/virtual/virtual-nodes-rels/) to display such graph :

```
MATCH (n:Product)<-[:TRANSACTION]-(c:Customer)
WITH n.category AS category, c, count(*) AS numberOfPurchases
WITH 
apoc.create.vNode(['Category'], {name: category}) AS catNode,
c,
numberOfPurchases
RETURN catNode, c, 
apoc.create.vRelationship(c, 'PURCHASED_IN_CATEGORY', {amount: numberOfPurchases}, catNode) AS rel
```

Comment: Brilliant, this works! I had to add a WHERE clause to filter out products with no category.

Comment: Does not work in neo4j Bloom however, maybe because it limits the search set?

Comment: No idea for Bloom, I'll ask